# Joint consistency of continuum real valued measurable and Martin maximum

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

What is known about the consistency strength of

ZFC + the continuum is real valued measurable + Martin's maximum?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Martin's maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_maximum) implies the continuum is $\aleph_2$, and therefore it is not real-valued measurable, since real-valued measurable cardinals must be limit cardinals and indeed weakly inaccessible and weakly Mahlo and more.

So unfortunately, what is known about your theory is that it is inconsistent.

Comment: What would be the consistency strength of $ZFC$+ "The continuum is real-valued measurable"?

Comment: This is equiconsistent with a measurable cardinal.  (A classical result of Solovay, I think.) For one direction, add $\kappa$ many random reals. For the other direction, use $L[N]$, where $N$ is the ideal of measure zero sets.

Comment: @Goldstern:  Thanks.  Regarding $ZFC$ + "There exists a measurable cardinal", would this imply the existence of many real-valued measurable cardinals (my guess is yes)?  I ask because I suppose (perhaps badly) that one could force the continuum to be any one of these  (real-valued measurable) cardinals....

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin The theory ZFC + "there exists a measurable cardinal" does not **imply** the existence of even one real-valued measurable cardinal, let alone many (unless you define "real-valued measurable" to include the possibility of being 2-valued measurable). It is merely **equiconsistent** with ZFC + "there exists a real-valued measurable cardinal" (as Goldstern wrote).

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  Thanks for correcting me.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

This is a supplement to Joel's answer:

In fact, even very weak forcing axioms are incompatible with the continuum being real-valued measurable.  For example, if the continuum $\mathfrak{c}$ is real-valued measurable, then $\mathfrak{b}<\mathfrak{c}$, where $\mathfrak{b}$ is the minimum cardinality of an unbounded family in $(\vphantom{b}^\omega\omega, <^*)$, and $f<^*g$ means $f(n)<g(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Martin's Axiom (and much weaker forcing axioms) implies $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{c}$, and hence implies that $\mathfrak{c}$ is not real-valued measurable.

Lemma 27.9 on page 304 Jech's Set Theory gives a slightly more general result, along with a proof.  (One needs to note that if $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{c}$, there is a $\mathfrak{c}$-scale.)

Comment: If one adopts some Gematria to these cardinal characteristics, then $\frak b=c$ is the same as $2=3$, which by subtracting $2$ from both sides gives us $0=1$. Ergo, Martin's Axiom and its large cardinal powered family are all inconsistent.

Comment: Give that man a 6-9-5-12-4-19 medal!